# what does @ mean when you use it in front of a meteor collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I found this code from yogiben:autoform-map package,

what does @ mean when you use it in front of a meteor collection?

```
Schemas = {}

@Cities = new Meteor.Collection('cities');

Schemas.Cities = new SimpleSchema
    name:
        type:String
        max: 60

    location:
        type: String
        autoform:
            type: 'map'
            afFieldInput:
                    geolocation: true
                    searchBox: true
                    autolocate: true

Cities.attachSchema(Schemas.Cities)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Meteor collection. The code is written in [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/). The @ in front denotes that Cities is a global object. From the coffee script website,

> As a shortcut for this.property, you can use @property.